# Photoshop: Area Type not working?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

Not sure if I'm missing something but the text isn't wrapping/continuing onto the next line within the area text box in Photoshop. It just hyphenates and disappears outside the bounding box. If I hit enter to force a line break same thing? I don't work with text in Photoshop much but I don't know what I'm missing.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the leading?

Comment: lol yes that was it, thanks. Haven't worked with text in Photoshop in a long time. Totally different from InDesign.

Comment: And.. if you have no *spaces or hyphens* in a line, there's no place to break the line.